# UI for an intended XSL-FO designer in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, designer, xsl-fo

I intend to write a XSL-FO designer in java for which i need to write an UI. The basic idea is to give the user a work pane wherein he/she can draw rectangles and these rectangles would in turn be associated to field containers in the underlying XSL-FO generator. Once the field container are done, the user should also be able to select any of the rectangles(field containers) created and add components into it. These will in turn be translated into field blocks that fall under the chosen field container.

Till now I have created a simple UI using JFames with mouseListeners hooked to them so that i can have users draw the rectangles on the work area.

Im stuck at the point on how to implement the part where the user selects one of the rectangles created in the previous steps.

Given the intent of the designer, is it possible to accomplish this using Jframes ?

Any pointers/suggestions on how i can achieve the motive of this designer would be of great help !

Please excuse me if any part of this post is noobish. I am one when it comes to UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JInternalFrame`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html) might be a starting point. You can connect them, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951383/cubiccurve2d-connecting-two-jinternalframe-instances/3952082#3952082), and add arbitrary components as required.

Comment: Looks interesting. I will try this out before accepting this as the answer.
Thanks !