# Setting drawString so (0,0) is inside the draw area

Tags: java, swing, drawstring

I have a problem which I for the life of me I cannot figure out.  I ask for user input and then it makes a JFrame and shows the word.  I want to display the word at (0,0) but this appears to be out of the field, and writing up in the top where the Title is.  Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;

public MainWindow(String input){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(320, 240);
    frame.setTitle("Draw String Example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Text text = new Text(input);
    frame.add(text);
    frame.setVisible(true); 
}

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
    String input = sc.nextLine();

    new MainWindow(input);
}
}
```

Then in my Text class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Text extends JComponent {
String text;

public Text(String txt){
    this.text = txt;
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawString(this.text, 0, 5);
}
}
```

So, if you run this you will see the bottom half of, for instance, hello.

if I set

```
this.text, 10, 10
```

then you can see the whole word.

Is there a way, to make (0,0) start at the top left most corner and have the text be completely inside the actual draw area?

Answer (score 2):

You can [`translate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#translate-int-int-) the origin of the graphics context so that it appears at the coordinates you specify. Subsequent calls to `drawString(…, 0, 0)` will render text with the [baseline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) at those coordinates. Use [`FontMetrics`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FontMetrics.html) to determine what coordinates to use. Examples shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11924118/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055215/230513) pass the coordinates to `drawString()`, but you can  pass them to `translate()` instead. Be sure to restore the origin when you're done.

```
FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
g2d.translate(0, fm.getAscent());
g2d.drawString(this.text, 0, 0);
g2d.translate(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Flow Layout or a Grid Layout to your JFrame and add a JLabel to set the text.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setText("Text");
frame.add(label);
frame.setVisible(true);
```